# How to overwrite a file upload so that the filename is always the same?

Tags: 8, forms, files

I am trying to implement a file upload form in which files are saved. I had written the following code

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\avenue_product_import\Form\avenue_product_importForm.
 */

namespace Drupal\avenue_product_import\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;

class AvenueForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'AvenueForm';
  }


  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['description'] = [
      '#markup' => '<p>Use this form to upload a CSV file of Data</p>',
    ];

    $form['import_csv'] = [
      '#type'              => 'managed_file',
      '#title'             => t('Upload file here'),
      '#upload_location'   => 'public://importcsv/',
      '#default_value'     => '',
      "#upload_validators" => ["file_validate_extensions" => ["csv"]],
      '#states'            => [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="File_type"]' => ['value' => t('Upload Your File')],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';


    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type'        => 'submit',
      '#value'       => $this->t('Upload CSV'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    /* Fetch the array of the file stored temporarily in database */
    $csv_file = $form_state->getValue('import_csv');

    /* Load the object of the file by it's fid */
    $file = File::load($csv_file[0]);

    /* Set the status flag permanent of the file object */
    $file->setPermanent();

    /* Save the file in database */
    $file->save();

    drupal_set_message('File Uploaded Successfully');
  }

}
```

But here the problem is if the filename in which I am uploading is same. It is getting renamed. But I want to replace old with the new one. How can I achieve this? I had seen `file_move()` and `file_save_upload()` function. What changes should I make to replace existing filename with the newly uploaded CSV file?

Comment: There is a thread on Drupal.org regarding this. Somewhere in core, when a file is saved with the file field widget or managed file, `FILE_EXISTS_RENAME` is the default with no way to override it yet. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2648816

Comment: If you do this, be sure to also adjust htaccess/caching rules in regards to Varnish etc if in use... so the browser gets the latest version of the file. We did this for a client for a file field containing PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would save always save the latest upload to `public://importcsv/avenue.csv`:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  /* Fetch the array of the file stored temporarily in database */
  $csv_file = $form_state->getValue('import_csv');

  /* Load the object of the file by it's fid */
  $file = File::load($csv_file[0]);

  $file_real_path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($csv_file->getFileUri());
  $file_contents = file_get_contents($file_real_path);
  file_unmanaged_save_data($file_contents, 'public://importcsv/avenue.csv', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

  drupal_set_message('File Uploaded Successfully');
}
```

Comment: In drupal 9, use $file = file_save_data($data, $fileLocation, 'EXISTS_REPLACE');

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 9 I was able to save the uploaded file so that the filename is always the same, as follows:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  // Loads file from upload form.
  $csv_file = $form_state->getValue('import_csv');
  $file = File::load($csv_file[0]);

  // Gets content from file.
  $file_real_path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($file->getFileUri());
  $file_contents = file_get_contents($file_real_path);

  // Saves new file with fixed name and replaces any existing file.
  \Drupal::service('file.repository')->writeData($file_contents, 'public://import.csv', FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);

  // Deletes the uploaded file.
  $file->delete();
  $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('The file has been uploaded.'));
}
```

I used Cesar's example as a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

You could check if a file exists with that name beforehand? If so, remove it and continue saving.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_delete/8.5.x

or

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!File!FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3Aunlink/8.2.x